# not able to check a key pressed in Python on macOS without echo

Tags: python, macos, terminal

In Python, I wanted to detect a key is pressed without using non-standard third-party libs, on macOS. Here is my test code:

```
import select
import sys
import termios
from time import sleep

def is_key_pressed():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    try:
        new_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        new_settings[3] = new_settings[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new_settings)

        ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
        return sys.stdin in ready
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_settings)

def main():
    print("Testing select:")
    sleep_time = 1 / 60

    while True:
        sleep(sleep_time)
        if is_key_pressed():
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It actually detects key pressed. But there is a problem: the input char is echoed. I tried to disable the echo by disabling `termios.ECHO` but it seems not working.

Here is the output of the test on macOS:

```
$ python test.py
Testing select:
1%
```

(Pressed the key '1' during the test).
A second question is:  why is there a `%` shown at the end ?

What I wanted:  no echo of '1', nor '%'.

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol) regarding the percent sign from zsh.

Comment: The problem with your design is the user might press the key during the sleep. Since you haven't yet disabled echoing, it will echo.

Comment: You should disable echoing when you start the script, not each time you check if a key was pressed.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct! I moved the setting outside the loop and do it when starting the script. Now it works. It seems that because I reset the old settings back in the loop, it will show the input key even though the echo was disabled briefly. Please feel free to move your comment to the answers section. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning echo on and off during the loop allows the user to type ahead while echo is on, and their input will be echoed.

Turn echo off before the loop, and turn it back on when the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

macOS / zsh only

You can simplify part of your code with tty.setraw() as follows:

```
import select
import sys
import termios
import tty
import os

os.environ["PROMPT_EOL_MARK"] = ""

def is_key_pressed():
    try:
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        attr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ready, *_ = select.select([fd], [], [], 0.25)
        return fd in ready
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, attr)

def main():
    print("Testing select:")

    while True:
        if is_key_pressed():
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```